# p - norms inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, normed-spaces, examples-counterexamples

For $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ denote by $||v||_p$ its p-norm. That is $(\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ where $v_i$ are the componenets of $v$.

I'm looking for a way to bound the following expression:
$$M_v=\frac{||v||_2^2||v||_4^4}{||v||_3^6}$$

Using Holder's inequality, and the fact that $||v||_2 \leq ||v||_3$ One can show that $M_v \leq n^{\frac{1}{3}}$. I'm wondering if that's the best possible bound.

If, for example, $v_i \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$ then it's easy to verify that $M_v$ scales like $\ln(n)$.

I'm unable to find an example for which $M_v$ is much larger than that. Intuitively, I would like to say that $M_v$ is bound by some logarithm, but I can't find a suitable proof or a counterexample.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: when $v_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$ then $||v||_2^2$ is the $n$'th harmonic number which is about $\ln(n)$. On the other hand both $||v||_4$ and $||v||_3$ remain bounded away by some constant. since they form the head of a converging series. Also note that $M_v$  is always larger than 1.

Comment: yes, you are right.